# Grabbing the top (or lowest) result from a row sorted by groups of ids?

Tags: mysql

So the title might be a little confusing because I'm a little confused myself. What I am trying to do is grab the lowest time of a completed map from a mysql database to display in a table on a website. 
The maps are sorted by an id (MapID) with a time on the same row.

Example of a couple of rows with same MapID (the time is in seconds):

```
MapID:    Time:
1         28.234
1         24.874
1         18.244
2         213.521
2         164.6
```

So I'd like to grab the lowest time from each MapID and be able to display that on a table in my site.
How would I query something like this?

Comment: why a tag php and html?

Comment: What is your primary key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like:

```
SELECT MapId, Min(Time) AS Time
FROM  mytable
GROUP BY MapId
 Output:
 MapId:    Time
 1         18.244
 2         164.6
```